# Unity ads displaying only unity products

Tags: unity, unity-ads

i just implemented unity ads on my project and now its only showing a single unity product each times. Can anyone suggest why? Thanks..

Here is some screenshot of the ad 
1:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG9vm.jpg)
2:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrS7x.jpg)

Can anyone tell me if this is even a real ad or just for testing?

Comment: you have to go to your unity panel and make a campaign or change any unwanted region limitation or age limitations. if you only receive one advertisement, it means there is only that ad that satisfies your limitations. im not sure that unity caches ads but check for internet connection. maybe it loads old ads of there is timeouts or...

Comment: @virtouso That looks to me like an answer. Want to write it up below so Sarwin can mark it accepted if it solves their problem?

Comment: @virtouso I have added a screenshot of the ad in the question above. Please check if it is even real?

Comment: @Sarwin if you oly see the image i saw it only means that you are in editor or debug mode. make an output with realdevice and production keystore. that should solve your problem.

Comment: @virtouso It was a real build on my phone signed with a key. Devloper console even acepted the app without issues.

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to your unity panel and make a **campaign** or change any unwanted **region** limitation or **age** limitations. if you only receive one advertisement, it means there is only that ad that satisfies your limitations.

im not sure that unity **caches** ads but check for internet connection. maybe it loads old ads of there is timeouts or...

Comment: Test mode is disable and also filter is off. I have tried clearing the app data and retrying but the same ad is popping up.